# How to change attribute value dynamically in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three set of columns. Each column having a different kind of data attribute name with integer value. The data attribute name value will change incremently 500 based on length of div.

This is my html structure,

```
<div class="column">
  <div data-0="100"></div>
  <div data-500="200"></div>
  <div data-1000="300"></div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div data-1500="400"></div>
  <div data-{increase value from prev child}="{increase value from prev child}"></div>
  <div data-increase value from prev child="{increase value from prev child}"></div>
<div data-{increase value from prev child}="{increase value from prev child}"></div>
  <div data-increase value from prev child="{increase value from prev child}"></div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div data-{increase value from prev child}="{increase value from prev child}"></div>
  <div data-increase value from prev child="{increase value from prev child}"></div>
<div data-{increase value from prev child}="{increase value from prev child}"></div>
  <div data-increase value from prev child="{increase value from prev child}"></div>
<div data-{increase value from prev child}="{increase value from prev child}"></div>
  <div data-increase value from prev child="{increase value from prev child}"></div>
</div>
```

How to achieve this logic with jquery?

Comment: do the divs exist or should they be created? does the first element with the initial value exist?

Comment: Yes. first element having the initial value.

Comment: @Sathya ok, hang on for example

Comment: Thanks @zedd. I'm waiting.

Comment: Were you after something [like this](http://cl.ly/image/3L2v043r312m)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the ways to do it. Look for comments inline.

```
//All columns
var $columns = $(".column");
//Grab the first div from the first column
var $firstColumnFirstChild = $columns.first().find("div").first();
//Grab the data attribute name (0) from '$firstColumnFirstChild' and convert it to number
var $firstColumnFirstChildKey = parseInt(Object.keys($firstColumnFirstChild.data()), 10);
//Set initial value
var $initial = 100;

//Go thru each div in all columns
$columns.find("div").each(function(_, elem) {

    //Set data attribute (name and value)
    $(elem).attr("data-" + $firstColumnFirstChildKey, $initial);
    //Increment for future divs
    $firstColumnFirstChildKey += 500;
    $initial += 100;
});
```

Here is [**a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8xvmge8x/) for the above.

Comment: Thanks @lshettyl... But i want to set more attribute for each div element. How to achieve this?

Comment: You can do that within the `each`, just like I did. `$(elem).attr('attr-name', 'attr-value');`

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there any way to increase value already existing attribute?
For example, my attribute value like, "data-1500". I want to increase this value through jquery from 1500 to 1800. How can i do this?

Comment: Yes, get it via `.attr('attr-name')` and set it back with `$(elem).attr('attr-name', 'attr-value-new')`

Answer (score 0):

Updated example with requirements:  https://jsfiddle.net/ozvkdw1p/1/

```
$(function() {
    var $col = $(".column")
    //grab first attribute of first element, extract values
    var initAttr = $("div", $col).get(0).attributes[0]
    var initName = parseInt(initAttr.name.split("-")[1])
    var initValue = parseInt(initAttr.value)
    $("div", $col).each(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr(this.attributes[0].name) //remove first attribute
        $(this).attr("data-" + initName, initValue) //add attribute with correct values
        //increment values for next iteration
        initName += 500 
        initValue += 100
    })
})
```

Grabs the data from the firts element, then updates the other elements with incrementing values

Comment: This function should work existing div element. I don't want to append div. @zedd

Answer (score -1):

You could archive this more easier using AngularJS framework. With this is is quite easy to combine javascript values with hmtl (-attributes, .. )

Comment: But, I want to achieve this one with jquery. Is there any way to an implement this logic?